# ion auth, users does not have any password

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, ion-auth

I'm new to Ion auth, so I've followed some tutorials to start.
I can log with the default admin account, and then create other users.

The problem is that other users cannot connect. And when I check
directly in the database, the default user has an usual string of ununderstandable
characters in the password case and the `salt` case is empty.
But my other users have `0` in the password case and the salt case contain `NULL`.

So I think that there is a problem in one of the sign up fonctions or in the config.

Does it ring a bell to anyone?

Here is the default user_create fonction:

```
function create_user()
{
    $this->data['title'] = "Create User";

    if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in() || !$this->ion_auth->is_admin())
    {
        redirect('auth', 'refresh');
    }

    $tables = $this->config->item('tables','ion_auth');

    //validate form input
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_fname_label'), 'required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_lname_label'), 'required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_email_label'), 'required|valid_email|is_unique['.$tables['users'].'.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_phone_label'), 'required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('company', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_company_label'), 'required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_password_label'), 'required|min_length[' . $this->config->item('min_password_length', 'ion_auth') . ']|max_length[' . $this->config->item('max_password_length', 'ion_auth') . ']|matches[password_confirm]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_confirm', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_password_confirm_label'), 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
    {
        $username = strtolower($this->input->post('first_name')) . ' ' . strtolower($this->input->post('last_name'));
        $email    = strtolower($this->input->post('email'));
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $additional_data = array(
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name'  => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'company'    => $this->input->post('company'),
            'phone'      => $this->input->post('phone'),
        );
    }
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true && $this->ion_auth->register($username, $password, $email, $additional_data))
    {
        //check to see if we are creating the user
        //redirect them back to the admin page
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
        redirect("auth", 'refresh');
    }
    else
    {
        //display the create user form
        //set the flash data error message if there is one
        $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : ($this->ion_auth->errors() ? $this->ion_auth->errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message')));

        $this->data['first_name'] = array(
            'name'  => 'first_name',
            'id'    => 'first_name',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('first_name'),
        );
        $this->data['last_name'] = array(
            'name'  => 'last_name',
            'id'    => 'last_name',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('last_name'),
        );
        $this->data['email'] = array(
            'name'  => 'email',
            'id'    => 'email',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('email'),
        );
        $this->data['company'] = array(
            'name'  => 'company',
            'id'    => 'company',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('company'),
        );
        $this->data['phone'] = array(
            'name'  => 'phone',
            'id'    => 'phone',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('phone'),
        );
        $this->data['password'] = array(
            'name'  => 'password',
            'id'    => 'password',
            'type'  => 'password',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('password'),
        );
        $this->data['password_confirm'] = array(
            'name'  => 'password_confirm',
            'id'    => 'password_confirm',
            'type'  => 'password',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('password_confirm'),
        );

        $this->_render_page('auth/create_user', $this->data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share `creating user process` codes?

Comment: I use the default "URL/auth/create_user" exemple given with ion auth.

Comment: May be `password` input return `empty`. Can you dump posted data to validation inputs like `var_dump($this->input->post());`

Comment: Thanks for the revisions. It is a nice improve for the showing. :) (And sorry for posting such a mess)

Comment: Hum, I just had an error message: "A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /*****/application/controllers/auth.php:438)

Filename: helpers/url_helper.php

Line Number: 540".   I'm taking a look at it and i come back to you with further informations.

Comment: So, the var_dump($this->input->post('password')); added in the code just before the last validation gived back the password i've entered. So the problem must occur in this line $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());

Comment: That line is only notification message. So try dumping `$password` on `register()` function in `libraries/ion_out.php` and `models/ion_auth_model.php`.

Comment: Done. I've put the dump in the two files, at the start and at the end of the register functions. When i create an account, all the dump show me the password i've entered. The issue most be even deeper. :/

Comment: Hmm.. So could you print this dump? `var_dump($password); exit();` after this line `$password   = $this->hash_password($password, $salt); ` in `models/ion_auth_model.php` `register()` function

Comment: Here is the result.    bool(false)

Comment: Something wrong around here! `hash_password` function return false only `$password` is empty.

Comment: Ok. Just to be sure, I have putted another var dump just before hash_password line.  Here is the result.  string(9) "testimony" bool(false).  So it seems the issue is in hash_password.  We are getting somewhere. thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means your server doesn't support bcrypt.  You should upgrade you're PHP version to >= 5.3.7.

If thats not a possibility you can change the hashing algo to SHA1 in the Ion Auth config file.

Comment: It works like a charm. I've changed the hashing algo to SHA1 as you suggested (because i do not have control over the server). The default acount cannot connect anymore. But that's normal, considering it was working under bcrypt. But all the account i create by now are working!  A great thanks!